# What am I doing wrong in finding $\lim_{x\to2} \frac{{(x^2-x-2)}^{30}}{{(x^3-12x+16)}^{10}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{{(x^2-x-2)}^{30}}{{(x^3-12x+16)}^{10}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{{(x-2)}^{30}(x+1)^{30}} {{(x-2)}^{20}(x+4)^{10}}$$

$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{{(x-2)}^{10}(x+1)^{30}} {{(x+4)^{10}}}$$

Why is it incorrect to get $0$ from that?

The answer in the book is $(\frac{3}{2})^{10}$.

Comment: Using Mathematica to verify the answer:`Limit[(x^2 - x - 2)^30/(x^3 - 12 x + 16)^10, x -> 2]`, and the result is 0.

Comment: @KemonoChen Oh, thank you! The book I am using is notable for the abundance of typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is fine and the answer **is** $0$.

Answer (score 8):

You derivation is fine, it seems there is a typo and the correct question is

$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{{(x^2-x-2)}^{\color{red}{20}}}{{(x^3-12x+16)}^{10}}$$